# 06 Suzuki 250 gz electrical issue

Tags: electrical

I lost my keys and had to order a new ignition. 
When I got the new ignition I plugged it in and it shorted out. I've checked my fuse's they all look good. Do you think that it could be the relay or a fusable link?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have got some wires crossed - some of the colors are different but **very** similar...

Worked on one for a friend and there were 4 different versions of "green" which he had managed to mix up - he had an excuse he was color blind so they all looked fine :)

So, make sure the colors match correctly.

Comment: ["Should I cut the blue wire with white stripes, or white wire with blue stripes?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_K_WmV50e7c) haha

Comment: @Sam THE RED ONE...